# Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /somepath/index.php on line 14

Tags: php, arrays, substring

I got a problem, I get an error with this code:

```
$totalpages = substr($totalpages[1],0,1);
```

The weird thing is, the code works?

This is the error i get:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 /some/spath.php on line XX</code>
```

Comment: What are you trying to calculate?

Comment: I'm not calculating anything, there's a string with the first character being a integer, I want this one in a variable.

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that an E_NOTICE denotes unclean code. This isn't necessarily the case.

Comment: I want it uberbugfree :P

Comment: An E_NOTICE is not a bug. It's a notice.

Comment: Sorry, I know that. I'm changing my code a little. I'm exploding it again on the second character in place of using substring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (isset($totalpages[1]))
  $totalpages = substr($totalpages[1],0,1);
```

BTW, you're getting a notice - not an error. That's the reason why your code still works.

Comment: Ah I was executing the code two times, it was in an for-loop. I didn't notice that. The first loop it went well, second didn't work. Fixed! Thnx guys.

Answer (score 2):

u should check `is_array($totalpages) ...`
or `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL  & ~E_NOTICE);`
more details on [error reporting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting)

Comment: My purpose isn't getting rid of the notice, but preventing it. I want clean code.

Comment: Tested <code>is_array</code>, and yes it's an array. It returns true.

Comment: further check isset($totalpages[1]) as other users suggested

Answer (score 1):

before you set totalpages to whatever value you set it to, set it as a array `$totalpages=array();` OR suppress the warning `$totalpages = substr(@$totalpages[1],0,1);`

Comment: It's an array, coming out an explode function :)
I'm going to try to set it as an array first.
My purpose isn't getting rid of the notice, but preventing it. I want clean code.